# How to know which set is most likely to have been generated by some probability distribution?

Tags: probability, distributions, mathematical-statistics

I have 3 sets of points in $R^n$: $X$, $A$ and $B$, how can I (preferably quickly) check which of the two sets $A$ and $B$ is most likely to have been generated by the same probability distribution as $X$ was generated by?

Comment: What assumptions are you making about that distribution?

Comment: Well you can assume it is smooth and bounded.

Comment: i just want to know which of A and B fits X best

Comment: What do you mean by "fit"? There are multiple possibilities.

Comment: "Smooth and bounded" is so weak that it makes the question almost unanswerable.

Comment: Well what I know is that one of these sets should be made from a distribution quite similar to that of X, so I want to find that, I may have many A,B,C.... There is a physical process producing these distributions.

Comment: Can you clarify your first sentence? Are $X$, $A$, and $B$ vectors with $n$ dimensions, or do you have a sample of size $n$ for each of them, which are univariate? Are the sample sizes the same for $X$, $A$, and $B$ ?

Comment: X, A and B are sets of vectors, the vectors are n long. X, and A have different size, but A and B have the same size

Comment: Following up on @Dave's comment, Da Beast it may be that $A$ fits one parameter (say, a location parameter) of $X$ very well, but that $B$ fits another parameter (say, a scale parameter) of $X$ very well. In such a case which is the better "fit"? It may also be the case that two mathematically different measures of fit on one parameter say two different things about whether $A$ "fits" $X$ better than $B$ or not.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

See en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Statistical_distance.

The most canonical distance measure seems to be the energy distance

$\int_{Domain} (p_X(x)-p_A(x))^2dx/{VolDomain}$

Answer (score 0):

Perform a two-sample Kolmogorov-Smirnov test between $X$ and $A$. Perform another two-sample KS test between $X$ and $B$. If the first test has the highest p-value, choose $A$. Otherwise choose $B$ as the most likely distribution.

Update: Given that you have vectors, you could do $n$ one-dimensional KS tests and see if there is a preponderance of p-values favoring $A$ or $B$. Another option: Look at Kullback-Leibler divergence.

Comment: I could believe this if $A$ and $B$ have equal sizes but not otherwise.

Comment: Which version of the KS test do you propose for these *vector* valued results (in $\mathbb{R}^n$)? What even justifies comparing p-values, especially if the datasets have different sizes?

Comment: OP has stated that $A$ and $B$ do have the same size.

Comment: Even so, your proposal to assess a "preponderance of p-values" is *ad hoc:* one can readily imagine circumstances in which it will give the wrong answer, no matter how "preponderance" is interpreted.

Comment: Of course. We know that "All models are wrong, but some are useful." OP has essentially asked for something quick and dirty. Truth "is much too complicated to allow for anything but approximations" (John von Neumann)

Comment: This is much worse than what is meant by the quotation: maybe all *statistical procedures* are imperfect -- but some are demonstrably poor.  This is one of them.